pkg-config --libs opencv4 command generates a very large list libs for the linker options, but I only need part of them
when generate the linker options, I use the command below:
pkg-config --libs opencv4
-lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_ovis -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core

You can see, this is a very long linker options. But I only need to link to two libraries, for example I only need the last two libraries: "-lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core".
So, my question is: How to use the pkg-config command to generate a partial libraries I needed? I think the long linker option line will make the linker stage a bit slower.
Thanks.
BTW, the opencv4.pc (in my MSYS2/MinGW64 platform) file has such contents:
# Package Information for pkg-config

prefix=/mingw64
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include/opencv4

Name: OpenCV
Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
Version: 4.9.0
Libs: -L${exec_prefix}/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_alphamat -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_cvv -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hdf -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_intensity_transform -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_mcc -lopencv_ovis -lopencv_quality -lopencv_rapid -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_viz -lopencv_wechat_qrcode -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
Libs.private: -lpthread
Cflags: -I${includedir}


If you already know that you only need -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core then
just put that in your linkage options, instead of
what pkg-config says. But you may as well do what pkg-config says because
sometimes it knows better than you, and sometimes future developments make
it right, and in any case nothing is linked into your program from libraries
it doesn't need (unless you coerce the linker to do that).

Hi, @MikeKinghan, thanks for the help. Indeed pkg-config knows better than me, if the library get updated, pkg-config always return the correct linker option for me. My concern is that if I explicitly write -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core in the linker option, in some day, the library name may change. "Nothing is linked into my program if it doesn't need it", I agree, thanks!
